# Delphi FloatToStr - Why is the display different?

Tags: delphi, floating-point

Using the **DEFAULT** FloatToStr function

```
FloatToStr('0.0000442615029219009')
```

outputs

```
4.42615029219009E-5
```

dropping one zero after the decimal place

```
FloatToStr('0.000442615029219009')
```

produces

```
0.000442615029219009
```

Can someone please explain why the value in the second case is not output to

```
4.42615029219009E-4
```

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't even ASK when floating point stuff behaves in an anomalous manner?  If it's floating point output and it's accurate to 0.001 or more, I am actually surprised.

Comment: @warren nothing anomolous here, other than a silly doc typo

Comment: I realize that. I was just being silly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [documentation for `FloatToStr`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FloatToStr) contains the answer:

> The conversion uses general number format with 15 significant digits.

To interpret that statement you need also to refer to the [topic describing the `Format`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Format) function, and specifically the text concerning the general number format (emphasis mine):

> The value is converted to the shortest possible decimal string using fixed or scientific format. The number of significant digits in the resulting string is given by the precision specifier in the format string; a default precision of 15 is assumed if no precision specifier is present. Trailing zeros are removed from the resulting string, and a decimal point appears only if necessary. The resulting string uses the fixed-point format if the number of digits to the left of the decimal point in the value is less than or equal to the specified precision, and **if the value is greater than or equal to 0.00001**. Otherwise the resulting string uses scientific format.

Unfortunately the documentation is in fact in error there. Instead of `0.00001` it should read `0.0001`. That this is illustrated by this program:

```
program FloatToStrScientificFixed;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  System.SysUtils;

var
  d: Double;

begin
  d := 0.0001;
  Writeln(FloatToStr(d*0.9999999));
  Writeln(FloatToStr(d));
  Writeln(FloatToStr(d*1.0000001));
  Readln;
end.
```

For your examples, `0.0000442615029219009` is less than `0.0001` and so is formatted using scientific notation. But `0.000442615029219009` is greater than `0.0001` and so gets formatted using fixed notation.

If you want your output always to use scientific notation then use `Format` with the `e` [format string](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Format).

---

[QC#107388](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=107388)

Answer (score 1):

Because the number of significant digits in your mantissa in the first example exceeds the number of digits to display, see

[Delphi Basics: FloatToStr](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=FloatToStr)

If you want to have more control over the formatting, use the FloatToStrF function instead.

**EDIT**: The explanation with the number of digits is not correct, see David Hefferman's answer for the correct explanation.

Comment: That explanation is incorrect. The actual discerning factor is whether or not the number is less than or greater than 1e-4.

Answer (score 1):

At some point `FloatToStr` function switches to the exponential format to limit the number characters in the output. Otherwise, displaying a `Double` may require up to 300 decimal digits, which is not practical for interpretation.

You can use `Format` function to specify strict rules.